# How does this code list all items from a folder?

Tags: c

On the human level, when a human opens a container, as long as there is light and things are not hiding behind each other, the human can see everything at once.

In the code below.. when the directory is opened, isn't there any light (info) ? doesn't it see everything at once ?

It is reading 1 item, and because it has read it, that item automatically disappears ? what makes it disappear ? there is no "`+1`" being added to a "`count`"..

and then it reads the next item as if it is the first item again.

almost as if everything is stack on top of each other, and it can not see anything other than what is at the top, and soon as it reads the top one, the top item disappears and the next one is pushed to the top for it to read ?

what is pushing it up ?

```
  DIR *d;
  struct dirent *dir;

  d = opendir("test/");

    while ((dir = readdir(d)) != NULL) {
      fputs(dir->d_name, stdout);
      fputs("\n", stdout);
    }

    closedir(d);
```

Comment: In general, a computer can't do multiple things "at once" unless it has separate computing cores which can work in parallel. On the "human level" you can't see things at once as well. You see only things you focus your attention on.

Comment: Not sure to understand well your question, but since you like metaphors, takes it as a book rather than a container. When you are done reading a page, you move to next page. This doesn't destroy the pages that you don't see, you just changed page

Comment: @Cid Some philosophers might argue with you on that :)

Comment: The OS does it for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the `readdir()` [linux man page entry](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html):

> The readdir() function returns a pointer to a dirent structure
>          representing the next directory entry in the directory stream pointed
>          to by dirp.  It returns NULL on reaching the end of the directory
>          stream or if an error occurred.

So the "+1" is inside `readdir()`. At this level nothing is really getting pushed down or up, but rather the directory listing is getting crawled and items examined one at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You need to read the documentation for the function in order to understand what it is doing. In unix, assuming the man pages are installed:

```
man readdir
```

It will state something similar to:

```
The readdir() function returns a pointer to a dirent structure
representing the next directory entry in the directory stream pointed
to by dirp.  It returns NULL on reaching the end of the directory
stream or if an error occurred.
```

That is internally, each time it calls that function it is populating it with the next info from the dir listing, so is handling the increment of any counts or pointers for you.

In terms of the 'seeing everything' at once. You are looing through each entry so handling one item at a time.